# POST JSON Object using Volley on Android to get Authentication Token

Tags: android, json, post, token, android-volley

I need to send a POST request to a server using the following JSON object format:

```
{"auth": {"tenantName": "<tenant>", "passwordCredentials": {"username": "<user>", "password": "<password>"}}}
```

to get an authentication token as response for subsequent requests:

```
{
access: {
token: {
issued_at: "2014-11-03T01:45:53.819103"
expires: "2014-11-03T02:45:53Z"
id: "686889ba4244432696aaac1d022f4973"
```

So far I'm just testing the connection with volley to see if I can get the proper response in a Toast:

```
public void loginRequest(){
    String[] credentials = getSharedPrefs();
    final String user = credentials[0];
    final String pass = credentials[1];
    final String url = credentials[2];

    JSONObject login = new JSONObject();
    JSONObject result = new JSONObject();
    try {
        JSONObject auth = login.getJSONObject("auth");
        JSONObject tenantName = auth.getJSONObject("tenantName");
        JSONObject passwordCredentials = auth.getJSONObject("passwordCredentials");
        JSONObject username = passwordCredentials.getJSONObject("username");
        JSONObject password = passwordCredentials.getJSONObject("password");
        login.put("tenantName","");
        login.put("username",user);
        login.put("password",pass);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    JsonObjectRequest getRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, login,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>()
            {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    // display response
                    // TO DO
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(Login.this,response.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP|Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL,0,120);
                    toast.show();

                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(Login.this, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
    ){

        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("tenantName", "");
            params.put("username", user);
            params.put("password", pass);
            return params;
        }

        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("Accept", "application/json");
            params.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
            return params;
        }

    };

        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        queue.add(getRequest);
    }
}
```

However I'm getting the following error:

```
E/Volley﹕ [893] NetworkDispatcher.run: Unhandled exception java.lang.RuntimeException: Bad URL
java.lang.RuntimeException: Bad URL
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:147)
        at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:110)
 Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException: Protocol not found:
        at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:176)
        at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:125)
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.performRequest(HurlStack.java:101)
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:96)
            at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:110)
```

Any idea what I'm missing?

EDIT: I did some more digging and realised the error above was caused by a wrong getter on the string "url". I fixed that but now I get:

```
E/Volley﹕ [787] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400 for http://10.10.10.10:5000/v2.0/tokens
```

It seems the code is not sending JSON properly. For instance if I try to send anything other than aplication/json to the site using the Advanced Rest Client I also get ***400 Bad Request***

Comment: i don't know ... maybe it means what it means "Bad URL" "MalformedURLException Protocol not found"

Comment: The URL is fine. I tested with the Advanced REST Client and I can get the token ok

Comment: no, it is not fine, it doesn't contains protocol aka schema ... just log and check

Comment: Sorry, I see what you mean... I forgot to paste it on the question. It's now there but I still get the error

Comment: Volley might add headers.  Use a proxy tool to see what those headers look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it work using a String:

```
        final String json = "{\"auth\": {\"tenantName\": \""+tnt+"\", \"passwordCredentials\": {\"username\": \""+user+"\", \"password\": \""+pass+"\"}}}";


        JSONObject login = null;
        try {
            login = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

However I still would like to know how to do it programatically using JSONObject to get to know the proper syntax. Any takers?

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.example.wexindemo;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.NetworkResponse;
import com.android.volley.ParseError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.Response.ErrorListener;
import com.android.volley.Response.Listener;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.HttpHeaderParser;

public class JsonObjectPostRequest extends Request<JSONObject> {

    private Map<String, String> mMap;

    private String params;

    private Listener<JSONObject> mListener;

    public JsonObjectPostRequest(String url, Listener<JSONObject> listener,
            ErrorListener errorListener, String params) {

        super(Request.Method.POST, url, errorListener);

        mListener = listener;


        this.params = params;

    }


    public JsonObjectPostRequest(String url, Listener<JSONObject> listener,
            ErrorListener errorListener, Map map) {

        super(Request.Method.POST, url, errorListener);

        mListener = listener;

        mMap = map;


    }

//  @Override
//  protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
//
//      return mMap;
//
//  }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
        Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
        headers.put("Charset", "UTF-8");
        headers.put("Content-Type", "application/x-javascript");
        headers.put("Accept-Encoding", "gzip,deflate");
        return headers;
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
        return params == null ? super.getBody() : params.getBytes();
    }

    @Override
    protected Response<JSONObject> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {

        try {

            String jsonString =

            new String(response.data,
                    HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));

            return Response.success(new JSONObject(jsonString),

            HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {

            return Response.error(new ParseError(e));

        } catch (JSONException je) {

            return Response.error(new ParseError(je));

        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void deliverResponse(JSONObject response) {

        mListener.onResponse(response);

    }

}

ps:You try to use this class to send a post request
```